# Spinner values NOT showing in Android 5.0

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am developing an Android app in which there is signup page. I need to show country data and I am using an Android spinner to show country data with an Array Adapter. I am using the following code:

```
country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.signup_countries_spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter201 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CountriesName);
country.setAdapter(adapter201);
country.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
        // getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus()
        // .getWindowToken(), 0);
        return false;
    }
});
country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        countrycode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup_code);
        countrycode.setText("+" + CountriesObjects.get(pos).getCalling_code());
        countrycode.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

This code works fine up to Android 4.4.4 but when the app runs on 5.0+, the dropdown doesn't show any values. I don't know what is causing the issue post 5.0.

Comment: And what about in other devices?

Comment: its working 100% fine upto 4.4.4

Comment: And of course you did some obvious checks like  what is CountriesName on 5.0 did adapter works with some hardcoded array, etc...

Comment: Yes it works and its working . again i am suggesting you to study about this question then answer it Thanks :)

Comment: And i'm suggesting you to ask a fairy with such little information ... :) Where is info about: what theme where is sipnner placed , does it have custom style ... and obviously definition of "doesn't show the values"(with image fx)

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
     ......
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter201 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CountriesName);
     adapter201.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     country.setAdapter(adapter201);
     .....
```

Comment: let me try this in a while